# Invalid X11-Window-ID if I want to close a Window I opened before. (C/C++)

Tags: c++, c, x11, cairo, xlib

I have a problem with X11. I created a normal Window and when I click onto a button I want to open a subwindow and draw something on it using cairo.

This is how I create the window:

```
printf("createCairoSurface called\n");
printf("Window created: %i\n", (int)appWindow);
cairo_surface_t* new_surface = cairo_xlib_surface_create(display, appWindow, DefaultVisual(display, 0), width, height);
```

Before these few lines of code I create a normal window with XCreateWindow and change a few properties so my window is positioned like a panel.

But when I try to close/destroy the window with the following code the application crashes and I get the BadWindow error.

```
Window window = (Window)static_cast(cairo_xlib_surface_get_drawable(surface));
printf("Tried to destroy window: %i\n", (int)window);
XDestroyWindow(display, window);
```

```
X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  20 (X_GetProperty)
  Resource id in failed request:  0x240000f
  Serial number of failed request:  344
  Current serial number in output stream:  344
```

Even so the printf-calls I added tell me that the window id should be valid:

```
Window created: 37748751
Tried to destroy window: 37748751
```

Thank's!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is related to request X_GetProperty eg. XGetProperty.

Your error is not coming from the XDestroyWindow() call, but for later use of the Window by your application.

Comment: Incidentally you can use XSynchronize(display, True) to temporarily make all calls synchronous, which kills performance but it's good for debugging because the crash will happen in the call that's actually causing the problem.